# Javascript Regular Expression Find and Replace Issue

Tags: javascript, html, regex

The following HTML does not have closing `</dt>` tags for each matching opening `<dt>` tag which is missing now.

For Example `<DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68924" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Entertainment</A>` (closing `</dt>` is missing here).

So, I decided to add the closing tag using regex. I am able to write the pattern for the finding a non-closed `<dt>` tag like

**regEx pattern for finding the not closed `<dt>` tags:**

```
<DT><A HREF=".*</A>
```

**Regex code to replace what i find using the previous pattern with closing `</dt>` tag**

```
<DT><A HREF=".*</A></DT>
```

But I got result as this string `<DT><A HREF=".*</A></DT>`, instead of just adding the closing `<dt>` tag I got this string everywhere I found the pattern.

Want to add the `</dt>` tag at the end of the pattern I found, either in IDE or via javascript is OK for me.

**HTML file:**

```
<DL>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1389093133" LAST_MODIFIED="1423897474">Links for United States</H3>
    <DL>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=129792" ADD_DATE="1389093133">GobiernoUSA.gov</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=129791" ADD_DATE="1389093133">USA.gov</A>
    </DL>
    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1389093133" LAST_MODIFIED="1423897474">MSN Websites</H3>
    <DL><p>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=55143" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Autos</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68924" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Entertainment</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68923" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Money</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68921" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Sports</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54729" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN</A>
        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68922" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSNBC News</A>
    </DL>

</DL>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, to find all non-closed `<DT>` tags, you need to check if there is no closing `</DT>` tag, and it can be done with a negative [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(<DT[^<]*><A HREF="[\s\S]*?<\/A>)(?!<\/DT>)
```

Replace with `$1</DT>`. Adding `i` option, we make sure we'll also capture `<dt>` tags.

`[\s\S]*?` will capture newlines, too. `[^<]*` in `<DT[^<]*>` will make sure we'll also capture `<DT>` tags with attributes.

See [demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/lH1gV1/3).

Sample code:

```
var re = /(<DT[^<]*><A HREF="[\s\S]*?<\/A>)(?!<\/DT>)/gi; 
var str = '<DL>\n    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1389093133" LAST_MODIFIED="1423897474">Links for United States</H3>\n    <DL>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=129792" ADD_DATE="1389093133">GobiernoUSA.gov</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=129791" ADD_DATE="1389093133">USA.gov</A>\n    </DL>\n    <DT><H3 ADD_DATE="1389093133" LAST_MODIFIED="1423897474">MSN Websites</H3>\n    <DL><p>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=55143" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Autos</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68924" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Entertainment</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68923" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Money</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68921" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN Sports</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=54729" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSN</A>\n        <DT><A HREF="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=68922" ADD_DATE="1389093133">MSNBC News</A>\n    </DL>\n\n</DL>';
var subst = '$1</DT>'; 
var result = str.replace(re, subst);
```

Comment: How to give the html file as a input to check for this expression? I am converting the entire file into single string and am checking the expression. is there any better way to do it?

Comment: If it is malformed as in your case, I am not sure there is a better way.

Comment: thanks for the demo, coul you help me on this plunkr, when i try to do this on myself i got stuck, not able to use backreference http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/dq3cs9d4/3/

Comment: Please check my update (http://jsfiddle.net/dq3cs9d4/4/), and if it is not what you expect, please let know what results you expect. I feel  it is a bit different question.

Comment: Here i try to use the backreference in the simple example as bman answered above, it is not working out for me. instead of "birdee" here i want to use the backreference and remove the "\*" in around the words "word" "bike" and "fork"

Comment: Looks like this is what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/dq3cs9d4/8/. I added a capturing group `(.*?)` and set the replacement string to `$1`.

Comment: @strbibizhev: could you please explain this part "[^<]*" , from the answer i guess to have attribute, but we can use something like to capture ".*" attributes, why negation of the "<" is used ?

Comment: `[^<]*` means *capture any symbol other than `<`, 0 or more times*. Since the attribute value is inside `>` and `<`, this regex is safe. It is also safe for attributes inside the opening tag node since `>` may not be serialized, and `<` must be serialized always.

Answer (score 2):

One of the features of Regular Expression replacement strings is [Backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html), in which you reference to the part of the string in the source string.

For backreferencing you need to specify a part of the search string using parenthesis, then you can backreference using `\n` pattern in which n refer to the `n-th` group.

In the following example, we put all the search string in parenthesis to make it a group that we can backreference to.

```
(<DT>.*</A>$)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1</DT>
```

Comment: Thanks For the help, could you do the backreference in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/shmdhussain/dq3cs9d4/3/ ...i am not able to do the backrefernce, could u help me?

Comment: @MohamedHussain your search string was set to be *greedy*. I removed the greediness, and now it works. In greedy mode, the engine tries to find the largest possible match, hence matching the very first asterisk mark to the very end asterisk mark.

Comment: I am struggling in using the backreference, could u use backreference in my fiddle... i tried removing the /g flag, still i got the entire maximum string

Comment: Take a look now @MohamedHussain. Just like this: `var str = a.replace(/\1/,"birdeee");` Tha part `\1` is the backreference.

Comment: check stribizhev answer there instead of "\1" for backreference , he used "$1".